# Let $G=D_4$. For $H=\langle a \rangle$, find $N_G(H)$

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $H$ a subgroup of $G$. Let $$G=D_4=\{ a,b \mid  a^4=e=b^2; ab=ba^{-1}\}$$

1. For $H=\langle a \rangle$, find $N_G(H)$
2. For $H=\langle b \rangle$, find $N_G(H)$

$$N_G(H)=\{g \in G\mid gHg^{-1}=H\}$$
$$\langle a \rangle=\{e,a,a^2,a^3\}$$
$$\langle b \rangle=\{e,b\}$$

$$D_4=\{e,a,a^2,a^3,b,ba,ba^2,ba^3\}$$

How would I find $N_G(H)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, depending on the tools you have at your disposal, you can approach these kinds of problems any number of ways.

For $1$, if you know the result that any subgroup of index $2$ is normal, you can conclude that $\langle a \rangle$ is a normal subgroup of $D_{4}$, hence $N_{G}(\langle a \rangle) = D_{4}$.

Alternatively, since $\langle a \rangle \subset N_{G}(\langle a \rangle)$ and $N_{G}(\langle a \rangle)$ is a subgroup of $D_{4}$, it follows that either $N_{G}(\langle a \rangle) = \langle a \rangle$ or $N_{G}(\langle a \rangle) = D_{4}$ (why? Comment if you need clarification on this). Hence, it suffices to see if $b \in N_{G}(\langle a \rangle)$.

For $2$, note that any element of $D_{4}$ that normalizes $\langle b \rangle$ are precisely the elements that commute with $b$ (why?). Hence, it suffices to compute the elements of $D_{4}$ that commute with $b$. (Hint: the relations on the generating elements of $D_{4}$ make this very easy)

Comment: Can you explain why $N_G(\langle a \rangle)=D_4$ or $\langle a \rangle$?

Comment: @UsernameUnknown: if you have Lagrange's theorem, then you can note that $N_{G}(\langle a \rangle)|8$ and $N_{G}(\langle a \rangle) \geq 4$, so $N_{G}(\langle a \rangle) =4$ or $8$. If you don't have Lagrange, suppose $N_{G}(\langle a \rangle)$ strictly contains $\langle a \rangle$. Then $ba^{i}$ for some $i \in \{0, 1, 2, 3\} \in N_{G}(\langle a \rangle)$. Can you show that $b \in N_{G}(\langle a \rangle)$?